# Blueimp Jquery File Upload is not working after page reload with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

When i load my page (containing the plugin) first time using jquery load function, the plugin works great, when reloading the page (same action with load) second time, the plugin is not working properly, it submits the form like there is no target to iframe; it is like the binder is no longer exist or is an old instance is causing problem... even if the initializing process is made when the page is loaded.
i tried destroy function but it does not solve the problem.

any suggestion to this issue. 
thanks in advance

Comment: you have to reinitialize plugin on new elements. You could do it in load method complete callback

Comment: If the content is loaded the second time, the plugin libraries (.js files) should NOT be loaded a second time, too. Either put them in the header or use requireJS.

Comment: thank you so much, i put js files in header so that they are not included other times and it works like charm. special thanks

Comment: @koppor: You should add an answer with the solution (similar to the comment, maybe a little more information) so that `user3094745` can select it as 'useful'. So when others have the same issue they can find a solution much faster by reading questions that have 'helpful' answers. ;)